# How to use Google Analytics API on WinRT with C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, google-analytics, windows-runtime, gdata-api

I'm developing a C# Windows Store app that has to connect to Google Analytics.

I found the [Google API Client Library For .NET](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/), but it doesn't work under WinRT.

It is possible to create my own wrappers around HttpClient, but I'd rather leave that as a worst-case scenario.

Can you suggest any other solutions for connecting to the API?

Answer (score 1):

The library that you provided the link to comes with [sources](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/). I'd suggest you download them and try to create a Windows Store class library out of it. This way you'll see how much it depends on APIs that are not available in .NET for Windows Store apps.

Since the library is just a wrapper around a web based API, it probably won't be that difficult to port. It'll certainnly be easier than writting your own wrappers.